# Background push notifications in Flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I have created a mobile app with Flutter, where I have a background listener for push notification from Firebase. When triggered it should alert the user (Similar to how opsGenie works ).
The problem I have is that this works only if the phone is not locked. If it's locked, the alert starts only after you unlock the phone. I kept looking for a solution but with no luck. and I am not sure if this would be because of a Flutter limitation or not?
Do you know btw, how opsgenie does it?